# Problema con tamaño de Select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, select2

Estoy con un problema que al inicializar un Select2 se modifica el tamaño y ya no sé cómo solucionar.

Así se ve el select normal.
[image: Así se ve el select normal.]

Así se ve después de inicializar el select2.

[image: Así se ve después de inicializar el select2.]

```js
$("#prove").select2({
    width: '500px',
    placeholder: "Seleccionar"
});

function cargarprove(n) {
    $.getJSON('comprasControlador', {accion: "cargarprove"}, function (r) {
        console.log("prove" + r);
        var contenidoHTML = "<option value=''></option>";
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            if (n === r[i].id_iva) {
                contenidoHTML += "<option  selected value='" + r[i].id_proveedores + "'>" + r[i].nombre + "</option>";
            } else {
                contenidoHTML += "<option value='" + r[i].id_proveedores + "'>" + r[i].nombre + "</option>";
            }

        }
        //agrega el contendio html
        $("#prove").html(contenidoHTML);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
          <select class="form-control  select2-multiple" id="prove"  name="educationDate[]">
              <option value="">Proveedor</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="RUC">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Nro. Factura">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fe" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Fecha">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Fabián, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir un ejemplo de código más completo en el que se pueda ver el problema. Seguramente es algo que tiene que ver con algún conflicto entre los estilos de la lista desplegable y los de select2, pero sin ver más código no podríamos decirte. También completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Hola, perdón es mi primera pregunta aquí. Ahora la actualizo

Comment: El problema puede ser que el select2 tenga su propio estilo y este pise el del form-control. Lo que necesitas es añadir un min-height:34px a tu css.

Comment: Probé quitando el form-control e igual sigue de la misma manera, No sé si agregué bien el min-height:34px en mi css, podrías decirme en qué parte del css tengo que agregarlo? Para estar más seguro. @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia

Answer (score 1):

select2 no cambia el tamaño, simplemente oculta tu `select` y te muestra otra cosa, por lo que veo estas usando bootstrap 4 así que para no tener este problema de apariencia puedes descargar el [select2-bootstrap4-theme](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme) que te cambiará la apariencia de forma que se vea igual al framework de bootstrap

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucioné de esa manera! :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes inicializar el elemento en JavaScript y seleccionar el theme de boostrap.

```
$('.select2').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap4"
        });
```